# How do I populate an empty column in my sql database?

Tags: sqlite

How do I populate an empty column in my sql database?

I have a list that I want in the last column of my database. If I use executemany it just adds rows on the bottom of my database. Is there a way to fill it from the top? The column is currently populated with NULL values.

Just to be clear. I want the first item in the list to be put in the first row and item n on the list to be put into row n.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `UPDATE tablexy SET columnxy = valuexy WHERE conditionxy`

Answer (score 0):

****Always take backup of your database, just incase you want to revert it back to original state.***

Each row in your database table should have a unique primary key. As you mentioned you have a list to be uploaded in the last column, I assume you have some kind of relationship that distinguishes which list item goes to which row in the last column of the table.

You an update a single row by simple update syntax as below:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET last_column = somevalue_from_list
WHERE id = unique_row_id;
```

If you want to update all the rows with the same value then

```
UPDATE table_name
SET last_column = one_value_for_all_rows;
```

Follow the below suggestion only when you are using phpmyadmin to manage your tables:
If you want to update each row with the unique value from the list then my suggestion will be to [export](https://hevodata.com/learn/mysql-export-to-csv/#php) your table in csv format, open in excel like software and add your last column values in last column of each row and then [import](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/import-csv-file-into-mysql#ftoc-heading-5) the changed table back to the database.

Hope this help.